Probability: Question about expected value with coins
In a coin purse, there are two one-dollar coins and one five-dollar coin. One randomly draws without replacement two coins and sets X = the value of the first coin, Y = the value of the second coin. Calculate E(X), E(Y).
So I was looking at my TA's notes and I see that they have written E(X) = E(Y). But I don't really get it? The chances that we pick a one dollar coin the second time is.
$\frac12 + 1 = \frac32$. And that we pick a 5 the second time is $\frac12 + 0 = \frac12$.  Aren't I right? Can anyone explain how the the expected value is still the same given that we have different probabilities now?

It's true, of course, that if you condition on the outcome of the first draw, the expectation of the second is different.  But the question is asking about the unconditioned expectation and each of the three coins is equally likely to be drawn in any given position.  Here, the numbers are so small that you can easily enumerate all the cases to confirm.

Should add:  I can't follow your calculation.  Clearly, no probability can equal $\frac 32$.

@lulu You're right. I was confused ignore what I said if you can lol. But I am still confused. How is expecation sitll the same, we don't even have the same number of coins anymore after the first take.

As I say,  in this case you can easily write out all the cases to confirm.

I am not really sure what you mean, maybe I am slow but I just don't get it at the moment.

Name the coins, $A,B,C$ say (with $C$ being the five dolllar coin).  Then there are only six cases, namely $AB, BA, AC, CA, BC, CB$ and these are all equally likely.  It's then clear that each coin has an equal chance of being either first or second.

None of the coins are more likely to be in any order than the other would you agree? So if we have 2 one dollar coins and 1 five dollar coin, we have
FOO,
OFO,
OOF
How many times does each coin show up in each place? What does that say about the expectation?
The reason the expectations are the same is because we are not conditioning on any information. In your second example:

And that we pick a 5 the second time is $\frac{1}{2}+0=\frac{1}{2}$

You are assuming you didn't pick 5 the first time.
